# How to decrease the lines of code for input validation?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am validating my editText for incorrect user input. The code is as follows:

```
if (text.isNotEmpty() && !Pattern.matches(
            "[a-zA-Z]+",
            text
        ) && !text.contains(",") && !Pattern.matches(
            "[А-яЁё][-А-яЁё]+", text
        ) && !text.contains("@") && !text.contains("+")
    )
```

I would like to reduce the number of lines, is it possible to check for + @ , character entry at once, without writing text.contains for each? I know I could have simply included the android:digits in XML, but user may copy paste the input,so decided to validate. Thank you

Comment: What is your condition? You mention you could have use `android:digits` if ignoring copy and paste, but your code doesn't seem to agree with that. `not matching [a-zA-Z]+` just means that the string cannot consist of ONLY alphabet. It can still contain alphabets. If your goal is to allow for number digits only, just check `Pattern.mathces("[0-9]+",text)`

Comment: My condition is it can contain only digits and dot ["."], it is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: the you just need to match `([0-9]|\.)+`

Comment: Pattern.matches("([0-9]|\\.)+", text) is right if I check so? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible to check for + @ , character entry at once, without writing text.contains for each?

You can use the `none` function.

```kotlin
if(text.none { it in ",@+" } && otherConditions)
```